# xhr.statusText exist in localhost but not in server

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

Good morning,

Trying on the physical server, the request does not return with the statusText which instead works perfectly in the localhost.
Example code js (framework7):

```
statusCode: {
            401: (xhr) => {
                console.log(xhr.statusText)
//other code
```

in php:

```
$protocol = (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] : 'HTTP/1.0');
die(header("$protocol 401 Error auth."));
```

Is there some setting in the php.ini that I am missing to return the text correctly to the server?

---

Seems like work only with that pattern:

```
http_response_code(401);
print_r('Error auth.');
exit;
```

`xhr.responseText` instead of `xhr.statusText`

Comment: Take the `header()` out of the `die()`

Comment: Useful note from the manual `Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. `

Comment: is a request to an API for that use `die` (and nothing is sent before)

Comment: And if you are trying to get the output from a `header()` call to become a piece of text you can use as a message, `header()` does not return anything, it schedules a header to be sent to the browser. See the prototype `header(string $header, bool $replace = true, int $response_code = 0): void`

Comment: In practice, if something goes wrong based on the conditions, access to the file is completely denied, returning the error which is printed via a dialog. To avoid executing the same code on every "success" I opted for an error like this. But why in localhost (xampp) work perfectly, the xhr object return `statusText` as i need?